# Cookie domain is always Empty in asp.net 4.5

Tags: asp.net, cookies, .net-4.5

I am always getting an empty value for cookie.Domain on read.

**It seems that you can only ever set the cookie domain, but never read it.**

Is this correct behaviour?

---

Here is an example:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Set Cookie" />
    <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Read Cookie" />
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Output"></asp:Label>
</div>
</form>
```

Code behind:

```
Private _cookieName As String = "TestCookie"

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    'create cookie:

    'Initialize FormsAuthentication
    'Reads the configuration and gets the cookie values and encryption keys for the given application
    FormsAuthentication.Initialize()

    Dim cookie As New HttpCookie(_cookieName)
    cookie.Domain = FormsAuthentication.CookieDomain
    cookie.Secure = FormsAuthentication.RequireSSL
    cookie.Value = "The cookie was set"
    cookie.Expires = Date.UtcNow.AddDays(1)
    Response.Cookies.Add(cookie)
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    'read cookie:
    Dim cookie As HttpCookie = Request.Cookies.Get(_cookieName)
    Label1.Text = "domain: " & cookie.Domain & "; value: " & cookie.Value
End Sub
```

My Web.Config contains:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <!--Allows authorization across sub domains-->
  <forms cookieless="UseCookies" defaultUrl="/" loginUrl="~/login/" protection="All" slidingExpiration="false" path="/" ticketCompatibilityMode="Framework40" 
         requireSSL="false" timeout="129600" name=".DEMO" domain=".demo.lan" />
</authentication>
```

When I run the demo above, and click the Set Cookie button, the following cookie is being set in the browser as expected:

```
TestCookie=The cookie was set; expires=Mon, 14 Jul 2014 11:52:01 GMT; path=/; domain=.demo.lan
```

When I try to read the cookie using Read Cookie function above, it reads the value but the domain is always Empty:

```
domain: ; value: The cookie was set
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can gauge , the cookie Domain value is Write only on .net

Comment: Yes, I have seen this, too. I am not sure if it is write-only or it is a bug of .net, but I am sure that I can not read the domain of a cookie. It is null always. If it is write-only god why Domain property has a getter, shouldn't it has only setter?.